# Maxe-tv install error

Tags: ppa, repository

I recently installed Ubuntu, and I want to add a PPA for MAXE-TV, however I get this error when I try and use the PPA:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/venerix/pkg/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also cannot download anything, and this is a pretty annoying issue.

What exactly is wrong?

I add first
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/pkg
It comes up a window saying that are you sure you want to install TV-MAXE 
and i click enter 
Then I write sudo apt-get update
and the errors up there comes up, it just says that it's uploading the file nothing else :/

Comment: Please review my edits, I tried to make your question more understandable but I am not 100% certain I captured everything you were aiming for.  (Also please don't use phrases like 'WTF', there's no need for obscenities here)

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/pkg
when i'm adding that i can confirm that i want to download the file but when i write in the terminal sudo apt-get update this error comes up

Comment: FYI, if you actually had read the output from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/pkg` you would have seen the "Supported Versions" line stops at 14.10, indicating you should't have added the PPA to begin with, and that the PPA is no longer updated or maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that you can't download *anything*, but I can say with certainty that the issue you're getting with that PPA is because the maintainer hasn't updated the PPA since Utopic Unicorn - which is 14.10 and is long past end of life.

There are no packages in that PPA for Artful, so you cannot use that PPA for Artful.  This is why you're getting the "does not have a Release file" error - there is no packages for Artful so the Release file doesn't exist.

You need to **remove** the PPA since you cannot use it - there is no other option to resolve this error.  You can remove it with the following command in the Terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/venerix-ubuntu-pkg*.list*
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again.

**You cannot use this repository for tv-maxe anymore.  It does not work. 
 You must remove this repository to get rid of that error about that repository.**

---

*(For 16.04 and earlier only)*

However, if you **absolutely need to use this software**, then you can try this solution from a comment on [this post on ubuntublueprint.com](http://www.ubuntublueprint.com/2016/01/tv-maxe-live-tv-on-ubuntu.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/tv-maxe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tv-maxe
```

**Either way** you need to remove the `venerix` PPA you installed earlier, using the above instructions I provide to do so.

Comment: I did what you said, but then when i try to install maxe tv it doesen't work what could be wrong, the same error comes up

Comment: @Simon Again, you **cannot use that repository**.  You need to remove the repository from the system with the commands I gave you.  You also **cannot install MAXE-TV** with that repository, because the repository **does not support** 17.10

Comment: If i download a earlier version of ubuntu, will it work then? :)

Comment: @SimonWahlgren No.  Use the instructions in my answer to remove teh venerix PPA.  Then use this entire set of commands and see if that helps to install the app: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/tv-maxe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tv-maxe`

Comment: okay,,, thanks you're really good at ubuntu so i can use tv-maxe in 17.10? so I don't need to dowgrade or anything :) okay, so all i do is to open the terminal, copy the first thing with the delete venerix and then past these last things? :)

Comment: @SimonWahlgren Yes, and let me know if that works or not.  I haven't tested that repository, nor would I.  So the standard "You use PPAs at your own risk!" warning is implied in that we can't verify the software is safe to use.

Comment: Okay I'll get back to u how it worked :-) thanks

Comment: It came up a little that it checcked if it existed but then E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/tv-maxe/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @SimonWahlgren then it's likely that the repository doesn't support ARtful.  You might have to go back to Xenial (16.04) to use this repository.  Unfortunately, I don't see any additional PPAs available with this software.  You can remove this latest tested repository by doing `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trebelnik-*.list*`

Comment: okay thanks i wish i was a genious like you on this :) thanks Thomas Ward :)